# IE11: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer-11

```
const header = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<MyComponent testprops={this.props.testprops}  />)
```

I am getting a "Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object." issue only in internet explorer 11.

When i remove the above code , it worksperfectly , i need the abpve code for window.print() with header

Fix:

```
const MyComponent = React.memo(props => {
   return (<span>Testing</span>)
})
```

changed to

```
class MyComponent extends PureComponent {
    return (<span>Testing</span>)
}
```

The React.memo throws error

Comment: Could you paste the code for `MyComponent`

Comment: It is a React.memo exported , i changed to functional component it works

Comment: From your last comment, It looks like you had solved your issue. I suggest you to post your solution as an answer and try to mark your own answer as an accepted answer for this question after 48 hrs, when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 1):

```
ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<MyComp />)
```

MyComp shouldn't constructed with `React.memo` or `<Fragment>`, IE11 throws Element type is invalid error for both.

Removing `React.memo` or `<Fragment>` will resolve the issue